# Error in adorn_ns in while doing target segmentation of clusters in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, hierarchical-clustering

Am just starting out in R and machine learning.
Am working on a hierarchical clustering problem where after getting clusters of attitudinal variables (e.g preference for a certain choice), I want to do target segmentation by combining the cluster information with demographic data ,I did not include in the clustering such as marital status to check how cluster groups behave in married vs non married people.  my code is as seen below.

```
 data %>%
  tabyl(clusters, marital) %>% 
  adorn_totals(c("row", "col")) %>% 
  adorn_percentages("row") %>%
  adorn_pct_formatting(digits = 2) %>%
  adorn_ns()
  Error in adorn_ns(.) : could not find function "adorn_ns"
```

The problem is the code throws this error,  Error in adorn_ns(.) : could not find function "adorn_ns"

I have tried all that I know , but I have not been able to solve this .

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example:  <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example> with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: I have resolved this by installing the janitor package which was a requirement.  Thanks